# ggplot2 extracting y axis values

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Hi I woulds like to know is there an easy way to extract y axis values from graph, for example I have

```
set.seed(20)
GG <- ggplot(data = data.frame(y=rnorm(20),x=1:20), aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_line()
```

[image]

I would like to get vector: c("-3","-2","-1","0","1","2"), maybe there is simple function which generates them from all values in data? Or maybe I can extract them from GG ?

**Edit**

```
data <- data.frame(y=c(4.99,99.20554),x=c(1,2))
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_line()
pretty(data$y)
[1]   0  20  40  60  80 100
```

[image]

function `pretty()` gives nice, but not the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axis label positions and texts are computed when the `GG` object is displayed. You can `build` the object and inspect it:

```
> build = ggplot_build(GG)
> build$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.labels
[1] "-3" "-2" "-1" "0"  "1"  "2" 
> build$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.major_source
[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1  2
```

Now I would suspect these things are *very* internal and possibly might change and break your code with a new version of `ggplot2`.

Comment: there won't be a new version of ggplot2